# Continuity at a point II

Tags: calculus

For a function $f$ to be continuous at a point $x_0$, is it necessary that there exists a ball centered at $x_0$ such that $f$ is continuous at all points within this ball? Put another way, does $f$ being continuous at a point imply that there are infinitely many points of continuity for some neighbourhood about this point?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is rational and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Not continuous. But can a function be continuous at and only at a single point in its range, or does continuity at a point imply continuity at other local points? The eps-del definition requires this?

Comment: $f$ as above is continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: ah, but your point is that f is continuous nowhere else?

Comment: Yes. It's continuous only at $x=0$.

Comment: awesome example, thank you!